# Avoid showing "back" for back button when navigation title is long in Swift

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar

There is a navigation in my project which I want to config it's navigation back item. 
First case: When the `UINavigation title` is long the title of back button is set to "back"

replacing back button title to "back"

[image]

Second case: when it is longer this "back" is not shown.

delete back button title and just show back icon

[image]

But I want to show just back icon in the first case too.

Comment: So basically you want to show only back arrow in both cases, right?

Comment: @Mamta exactly I want to do this.

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 3 - Through Storyboard:**

To make navigation bar back button have only back arrow and no "Back" text written, follow the steps:

Go to navigation bar of the root view controller(titled "Home" in screenshot below)[image]

Go to its attribute inspector. Set the back button to a space as shown below:

[image]

And that's it!!

This is the simulator screenshot:

[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks. but I want to do this in code and show back title when title of navigation is not long .

Comment: @Bita please reframe your question properly. Some places you are writing that you want only back arrow in both cases and in comments you have written a contradictory statement.

Comment: I have xib file instead of storyboard.I cant find this attribute of back button .

Comment: @Bita I won't be able to help you with xib. I have never worked on it

Answer (score 3):

Add this in `viewDidLoad` of ViewController which is pushing next ViewController (View Controller Linguini Arabbiatta)

```
navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
```

It will show just a back icon in all the View Controllers which are pushed from that View Controller.

Comment: I want to show title of back button when title of navigation is not long . but your answer will be hide title of back button in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
if let title = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backItem?.title {

    if title.characters.count > 5 {
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backItem?.title = "Anything Else"
    }
}
```

Comment: why 5 character ?

Comment: @Bita : Fangming has just given the solution, you can add whatever number you want to the condition based on your requirement.

Comment: if you want to use this workaround you should be aware that "back" will be translated if you use your app in a different language, thus 5 might not work for all your translations. you would need to check if the title is the expected controller title and set it to "" otherwise

Answer (score -4):

Here's Objective-C

```
[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES];
```

Here's Swift

```
self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated:true);
```

Edit: if you wish to remove the text only, then here's Objective-C

```
[self.navigationItem.title = @""];
```

Here's Swift

```
self.navigationItem.title = ""
```

Then you'll need to refresh the nav bar

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setNeedsLayout()
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setNeedsDisplay()
```

Comment: This completely hides the back button arrow and its text and thus is not the answer to the question.

Comment: Please read the question properly. This solution will hide the back button completely instead of just removing the text.